# jQuery UI autocomplete display configurations

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am new to [JQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), is there any way we can configure the input so when people input an label, corresponding values show up for selection? So far I can only make people select other labels using {label:"label1", value:"value1" ...}.

I want to have a input that accepts label and pop up appropriate values for selection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var labels = ["CG", "AI", "CV", "RMI", "JE", "JI", "JA"];
            var values = ["Computer Graphics", "Artificial Intelligence", "Computer Vision",
            "Remote Method Invocation", "Java - Elementary", "Java - Intermediate",
            "Java - Advanced"]

        $(".tags").autocomplete({
            source : function(req, response){
                var reg = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
                var matcher = new RegExp("^"+reg, "i");
                var d = [];
                var a = $.grep(labels, function(item, index){
                var found = matcher.test(item);
                    if(found){
                        d.push(values[index]);
                    }
                    return found;
                });
                response(d);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
<input type="text" class="tags"/>
</body>
</html>
```